# How to add two responses to one onclick function? The onclick in html is

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to get a click function to do something new if other clicks are used. I have three `onclick` functions each with individual feedback statements when clicked. The `div`s they are attached to look like this:

```js
$('#p26_opt1, #p26_opt2, #p26_opt3').click(function() {
  // check whether this div was selected already
  var wasSelected = $(this).data('selected');
  document.getElementById("p26_feedback1").style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById("p26_feedback2").style.display = 'none';

  // change its selected state to the opposite of what it was before
  $(this).data('selected', !wasSelected);

  // keep track of whether any checkboxes are un-checked with a flag
  var anyUnselected;

  // iterate through all the divs
  $('#p26_opt1, #p26_opt2, #p26_opt3').each(function() {
    // if there was already an un-selected div, or if this div is
    // un-selected, set our flag
    anyUnselected = anyUnselected || !$(this).data('selected');
  });
  // if our flag indicates any were un-seelcted, stop here
  if (anySelected) return;

  // do whatever you want to do when all three are checked.
  $('#p26_feedback3').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="p26_options">

  <div id="p26_opt1">Periodically review the data stored on your devices to determine what you no longer need</div>
  <br>

  <div id="p26_opt2">Delete the data and empty the recycle bin</div>
  <br>

  <div id="p26_opt3">Follow the Defense Department guidelines to get rid of all traces of the data on your computer</div>
  <br>

  <div id="p26_opt4">Put it on your to do list for next week</div>
  <br>
</div>

<div id="p26_feedback1">And what else should you do? There are more correct answers.</div>

<div id="p26_feedback2">Not quite &ndash; why not do it now instead? Please try again.</div>

<div id="p26_feedback3">Yes! To completely dispose of electronic data, you need to review and identify old data, delete it and empty your recycle bin and take further measures to get rid of all traces of it on your device.</div>
```

I can select each choice and get separate responses. My question is how do I make a second feedback statement display only if all three are selected at same time?

Comment: Show us some code. It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking "how do I do X when multiple inputs are 'selected' (eg. when multiple checkboxes are checked).  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, whenever you want to do anything in response to something happening, you have to tie your logic to a handler for a relevant event that corresponds to the "something happening".  In this case, the relevant part of your scenario is that you want to check which elements are selected *when the user clicks on one*. Having identified that that the "click" is the event you want to target, your next step is to add an `onClick` handler.

Specifically, what you want to do is add an `onClick` handler to all three elements which checks whether the other two are checked (and if so creates the desired feedback).  For instance, say you have three checkboxes all with a class "checkbox":

```
$('.checkbox').click(function() {
     // keep track of whether any checkboxes are un-checked with a flag
     var anyUnchecked;
     // iterate through all the checkboxes
     $('.checkbox').each(function() {
         // if there was already an un-checked checkbox, or if this checkbox is
         // un-checked, set our flag
         anyUnchecked = anyUnchecked || !$(this).is(':checked');
     });
     // if our flag indicates any were un-checked, stop here
     if (anyUnchecked) return;

     // do whatever you want to do when all three are checked.
     $('#secondaryFeedbackStatement').show();
});
```

**- EDIT -**

Since you're not dealing with checkboxes (which keep track of their own state), you'll need to track whether or not each `<div>` is selected somehow.  Luckily jQuery provides a mechanism for saving arbitrary data on elements, called `data`.  Here's how you could use it:

```
$('#p26_opt1, #p26_opt2, #p26_opt3').click(function() {
     // check whether this div was selected already
     var wasSelected = $(this).data('selected');

     // change its selected state to the opposite of what it was before
     $(this).data('selected', !wasSelected);

     // keep track of whether any checkboxes are un-checked with a flag
     var anyUnselected;

 // iterate through all the divs
     $('#p26_opt1, #p26_opt2, #p26_opt3').each(function() {
         // if there was already an un-selected div, or if this div is
         // un-selected, set our flag
         anyUnselected = anyUnselected || !$(this).data('selected');
     });
     // if our flag indicates any were un-seelcted, stop here
     if (anySelected) return;

     // do whatever you want to do when all three are checked.
     $('#secondaryFeedbackStatement').show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks machineghost I'm not using checkboxes here's what it looks like

Comment: <div id="p26_opt1" onclick="p26_opt1()">Periodically review the data stored on your devices to determine what you no longer need</div>

Comment: Ok, first off, I recommend editing your question and adding that information; right now your question is about to be closed for not being clear about what you're asking.

Comment: Secondly, I've updated my answer to better describe your scenario.

Comment: Actually I just realized you might not have edit permissions yet, so I took the liberty of updating the question for you.  Also, a quick note: while your scenario relied on literal `onClick` attributes, the way I hooked up the `click` handler (with `$(...).click(...)`) is widely regarded as the preferred approach, since inline Javascript can quickly become difficult to maintain.

Comment: No problem.  Proper etiquette here would be for you to accept one of the answers given (either mine or HC_'s, depending on which answered your question better) by clicking on the checkmark next to them.  If you found both answers helpful you can "upvote" them as well (by clicking on the up arrow), but you can only accept one.  Also, you may wish to edit your question to make it clearer what you were trying to understand, and then click the "reopen" link (although, since you've already gotten your answer, that's not strictly necessary, just nice for posterity).

Comment: I just tried the code machineghost and when I select all 3 nothing happens any thoughts?

Comment: I understand I am new to this and apologize for any disrespect.

Comment: None taken :-)  Just wanted to clue you in to Stack Overflow practices.  

Could you please edit your question (since it's awkward to put this stuff in comments) and provide: A) the HTML of all three divs, B) how you're hooking up the Javascript, C) the Javascript you're using?  Without that information it's difficult for me to be helpful.

Comment: I ran it again and got this error Uncaught ReferenceError: anySelected is not defined

Comment: Hi machineghost I have one more small question. How do I change the background color for each statement when clicked. One blue one green and one yellow? Ive been trying all dy with no luck unless I make them separate click functions taking me out of what you composed for me

Comment: On StackOverflow it's best not to start a new question in the comments; instead you should start it as a new SO question.  But the general idea would be to do something like: `if (this.id == 'p26_opt1') $(this).css({backgroundColor: 'red'}); else if (this.id == 'p26_opt2') $(this).css({backgroundColor: 'green'})` inside the click handler.  You could also use a `switch`/`case`: `switch(this.id) case 'p26_opt1': $(this).css({backgroundColor: 'green'}); break; case 'p26_opt2': ...`.

Comment: Sorry again I am getting an education in Stack Flow lol! Thanks I'm all set now. You have inspired me to master jquery and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var a = false
    var b = false
    var c = false

onclickA(){
     //general onclickA code
     a = true
     if (a && b && c){
        //execute your desired code  
     }
}

onclickB(){
     //general onclickBcode
     b = true
     if (a && b && c){
        //execute your desired code  
     }
}
onclickC(){
     //general onclickC code
     c = true
     if (a && b && c){
        //execute your desired code  
     }
}
```

if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks HC I'll give it a try now